# Using Net::Google::Drive::Simple to download all a spreadsheet's sheets as CSV

Tags: perl

I'm writing a script that pulls down spreadsheets Google Drive using `Net::Google::Drive::Simple` for further processing. I'd like to parse them with Perl, so I'd prefer to download them as CSV files and spare myself some processing trouble.

Unfortunately, I'm finding that only the first sheet is getting exported as a CSV file. Is there a way to use this interface to get the other sheets?

EDIT:

Sample of the code, but it's honestly pretty rudimentary:

```
my $gd = Net::Google::Drive::Simple->new();

my $children = $gd->children( "/My Spreadsheets" );

foreach my $character ( @$children ) {

    next if $character->is_folder;

    print "\nFILE: " . $character->title . "\n";

    foreach my $type (keys %{$character->exportLinks()}) {
        print "TYPE: $type, LINK: " . $character->exportLinks()->{$type} . "\n";
    }
}
```

That list of exports produces a single CSV file that represents the first sheet. Not seeing any indications of how to get to the second or subsequent sheets.

Comment: Where is sample of your code? Or you suggest that we guess what you do in your code?

Comment: Please go to [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets), select your document and desired **Sheet**, then attempt to export it **File->Download->Comma Separated Values (.cvs, current sheet)**. Probably _Google Sheets_ allows to export only one sheet at a time. I assume that [Net::Google::Drive::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Google::Drive::Simple) only allows to manipulate files (download/upload,create,move,delete) and the features you are after is in [Net::Google::Spreadsheets](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Google::Spreadsheets).

Comment: I guess that it is a limitation of the `CVS` format -- it does not allow several **sheets** in one document. `Net::Google::Drive::Simple` module is not designed to manipulates the structure of the document, but manipulates files only.

Comment: I'll tinker with Net::Google::Spreadsheets when I get home and see if I can get something to work. For the problem I'm actually trying to solve, the solution was to just download the file as an Excel document; parsing that format was way easier than I anticipated. Still, I plan to keep an eye on this question and flag the solution just in case anybody with a similar problem comes along.